# onclick event of jquery mobile gridview

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, gridview

I have designed an chart using the default grid view of jquery for speed and time. I want to obtain the speed of the vehicle from the table.

Here is the design

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Home Screen</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="ui-grid-d" id="SpeedLevel">
                <div class="ui-block-a"
                    style="border: 1px solid black; border-bottom:none; text-align: center; height:100px;width:5%;">
                    <p></p>
                </div>

                <div class="ui-block-b"
                    style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; height:100px; width:5%;">
                    <p>super fast</p>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c"
                    style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; height:100px;width:30%;">
                    <span>S1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-d"
                    style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; height:100px;width:30%;">
                    <span>S2</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-e"
                    style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; height:100px;width:30%;">
                    <span>S3</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-a rotate"
                    style="border: 1px solid black; border-bottom:none; border-top:none; text-align: center; height:100px;width:5%;">
                    <p>Speed</p>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"
                    style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; height:100px;width:5%;">
                    <p>Faster</p>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c"
                    style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; height:100px;width:30%;">
                    <span>S4</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-d"
                    style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; height:100px;width:30%;">
                    <span>S5</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-e"
                    style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; height:100px;width:30%;">
                    <span>S6</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-a"
                    style="border: 1px solid black;border-top:none; text-align: center; height:100px;width:5%;">
                    <p></p>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"
                    style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; height:100px;width:5%;">
                    <p>Fast</p>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c"
                    style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; height:100px;width:30%;">
                    <span>S7</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-d"
                    style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; height:100px;width:30%;">
                    <span>S8</span>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-e"
                    style="border: 1px solid black; text-align: center; height:100px;width:30%;">
                    <span>S9</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-solo" style="border: 1px solid black; text-align:center; height:30px;">
                <span>Time</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the onclick i have tried, and i am able to click on all the cells and obtain the data.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#home', function() {
    alert("in page");
    $('#SpeedLevel>div').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
//      alert("sdfa");
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Now i need to make only S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6,S7,S8,S9 cells as clickable and when i click on those cells i need to obtain the corresponding values..

How can i do that??

Thanks in advance:):)

Answer (score 2):

The below lines did the trick for me.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#home', function() {
    alert("in page");
    $('#SpeedLevel>.ui-block-c,.ui-block-d,.ui-block-e').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#SpeedLevel  div ').click(function(e) {
   alert($(this).find('span')[0].textContent)
});
```

Comment: Bro thanks for the answer. but with your answer i am not able to select only specified cells.

Comment: What do you mean by cell ? each div with its own class ? You can get it doing: **$(this)[N]** is each div, within the funcion.